# how to create log file in device using cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, logging, device

I want to create log file in device using [cordova framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-logtofile).

can any one having experience in developing app in cordova who give proper direction and also guide to solve my query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [logging plugin](https://github.com/andischerer/cordova-plugin-logtofile)
which logs the error to local file system.

If the logfile exceeds a filesize above 5MB the current logfile will be archived and zipped into the current logfiledirectory. The last 3 archived logfiles will be retained, older logs get deleted.

Comment: I tried this but not able to log. I'm getting class not found when I try below script.


    window.logToFile.setLogfilePath(logPath, function () {
      console.log("Logger Logpath set Successfully")
    }, function (err) {
      console.log("Logger Logpath not set", err)
    });